# Tennis Players Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

Five tennis players of USA were asked to rank 5 football teams - P, Q, R, S and T - of other countries from 1 to 5 as per their performances in last year’s tournament, where rank 1 being the highest and rank 5 being the lowest. Team P was ranked same by all the five players while team Q was ranked same by exactly 4 players. Team R was given the same rank by 3 players and another same rank by 2 players. Team S was given the same rank by 3 players and two different ranks by the other 2 players and team T was ranked same by only 2 players and ranked different by the other 3. At the end, each team was assigned a final rank equivalent to the rank that was assigned to that team by maximum number of players. All five teams had different final ranks and final ranks of teams P, Q and R were 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Also, team R was ranked 4 by exactly two players. Each player had given a different ranking to each of the five teams.

Find the sum of the two ranks given to the team S, which were different from the same rank given by the three players?

Pls tell approach.

Source : https://www.imsindia.com/

Comment: Is this question made by you or from somewhere else? If it is from somewhere else make sure you are allowed to post this question on different platforms. If you are certain you are allowed to share it here please include the source in the question.

Comment: Sam, I thought you were going to stop posting questions taken verbatim from imsindia.com without their consent.

Comment: I have changed the question somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't yet checked if there is only one solution, but here is one that I have found:

> The sum of the two ranks given to team S that were different is 7.

List of rankings:

> ```
> __|P|Q|R|S|T 
> P1|1|2|3|5|4 
> P2|1|2|3|5|4 
> P3|1|2|4|5|3 
> P4|1|2|4|3|5 
> P5|1|5|3|4|2 
> ____________
> FR|1|2|3|5|4
> ```
>
> With this ranking setup The two different rankings for team S are 3 and 4 which sum together to 7.

Comment: There are multiple scenarios for this puzzle. Pls have a look at it.

Comment: Can you tell why is this puzzle downvoted?

Comment: Hard to say what specifically caused people to downvote. Some people may have downvoted because of the previous lack of source, others may have found the formatting of the question as a large wall of text off-putting. There have also recently been a lot of questions of this style that are from outside places that look like someone just copy and pasted a question with no real research or effort, the two key things people look for to upvote. If you would like to have some better performing questions I'd recommend reading through some of the tips in the help center and looking at other questions.